# 2-Way-Databinding not working in AngularJS from factory with MEAN-Stack

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, 2-way-object-databinding

I'm trying to build a single-page-app which lists some files from my local database (MongoDB), but AngularJS doesn't show me the data. When i get them from the Express-API via Postman, everything is ok. I get them through a controller, which calls a factory and this is getting the data. But when I delete a File from the database, AngularJS isn't updating the table. When I reload the page, it show's the correct data without the deleted item, but why isn't the 2-way-databinding working?

This is the Table-Content in my index.html:

```
  <div ng-controller="FileCtrl">
    <div ng-hide="files.length" class="alert alert-warning">Noch keine Files vorhanden!</div>
    <table ng-show="files.length" class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Path</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="file in filtered = (files | filter:searchtext | orderBy: 'name')" class="files-item">
        <td>{{file._id}}</td>
        <td>{{file.name}}</td>
        <td>{{file.path}}</td>
        <td><a href class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="fileFactory.playFile(file);">Play</a></td>
        <td><a href class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="fileFactory.removeFile(file._id);">Delete</a> </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

And this is my app.js:

```
angular.module('picube', [])
.factory('fileFactory', function($http) {

    var files = [];
    return {
        getFiles: function(callback) {
            $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/files/').then(function (Response) {   //takes all files from the api, tested with postman
                files = Response.data;  //Update Data
                callback(files);
            });
        },

        postFile: function(filepath){
            $http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/files/", filepath).then(function (Response) {   //adds a new file to the server-api, tested with postman
                files = Response.data;  //Update Data
            });
        },

        playFile: function(filepath){   //this is not important at the moment
            console.log("Play called");
            console.log(filepath);
        },

        removeFile: function(_id){ //deletes a file from server, tested with postman
            $http.delete("http://localhost:8080/api/files/" + _id).then(function(callback){
                files = callback.data;  //Update Data
            });
        }
    };
})
.controller('FileCtrl', function($scope, fileFactory) {
    $scope.fileFactory = fileFactory;

    init();

    function init() {
        fileFactory.getFiles(function(files){
            $scope.files = fileFactory.files;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use angular.copy to preserve the reference, otherwise you'll overwrite it and break two-way binding:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/files/').then(function (Response) {   //takes all files from the api, tested with postman
   files.length = 0; // clear the array
   angular.copy(Response.data, files);  //Update Data
        ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented my DB handling using ngresource/$resource factory instead of $http (more info available with an example at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#!).

However, it should work also ok with $http as well. I did my "removeFile"-equivalent so that I actually either read the data from the server using GET after the delete, or when data amounts get big, it is better to just use splice -method on the file[] array using index parameter - here is my proposal for modified version for you to try:

```
...
 removeFile: function(_id, index){ //deletes a file from server, tested with postman
        $http.delete("http://localhost:8080/api/files/" + _id).then(function(callback){
            $scope.files.splice(index, 1);
        });
    }
...
```

and correspondingly in the .html, call to this to include $index:

```
...
<td>
    <a href class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click = "fileFactory.removeFile(file._id, $index)">Delete</a>
</td>
...
```

Rationale here is that I don't think your Delete -method responds with updated full files list - at least usually they don't but you must yourself update the local contents .

Hope this helps...

Comment: It does respond with the full files list. and this is the reason, why i overwrite the local files[] with the response from express.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now it works.
The problem was the files.length = 0, which is causing the error.

The reason is, that angular.copy clears the array itself (see here: [array.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)).
This works:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/files/').then(function (Response) {
     angular.copy(Response.data, files);
});
```